# Proving an equivalence in the Smoothness Criteria for Tensor Fields in the book by Lee

Tags: differential-geometry

I am trying to prove an equivalence in the smoothness criteria for tensor fields theorem found in the book Introduction to Smooth Manifolds by John M. Lee, Second Edition, p. 317. It is stated as follows (just taking the essential parts):

> Let $M$ be a smooth manifold and let $A : M \to T^kT^*M$ be a rough section. Then the following two conditions are equivalent:
>
> (a) If $X_1,\dots,X_k \in \mathfrak{X}(M)$, then the function
>   $A(X_1,\dots,X_k): M \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $$A(X_1,\dots,X_k)(p) := A_p(X_1\vert_p,\dots,X_k\vert_p)$$ is smooth.
>
> (b) Whenever $X_1,\dots,X_k$ are smooth vector fields defined on some open subset $U \subseteq M$, the function $A(X_1,\dots,X_k)$ is smooth on $U$.

I try to prove (a)$\Rightarrow$(b). I think a direct proof would be the best idea. So let $U \subseteq M$ be open and $X_1,\dots,X_k \in \mathfrak{X}(U)$. Since $T_pU \cong T_pM$ $$A_p(X_1\vert_p,\dots,X_k\vert_p)$$ makes sense. Now it is clear that I have to invoke that smoothness is a local property and (a), but somehow I do not quite see how this should be done. Also I am slightly confused, if what I did until now is right, i.e. if I understood the formulation of (b) correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume (b) does not hold. Let $U$ be an open set, and let $X_1,\ldots,X_k$ be smooth vector fields on $U$ such that $p\mapsto A(X_1(p),\ldots,X_k(p))$ is not smooth on $U$. Then there is a specific point $q\in U$, such that the above function is not smooth at $q$. Now, one of the ways to proceed is by the following

**Lemma:** There exist an open set $V\subset U$ containing $q$ and global smooth vector fields $Y_1,\ldots Y_k$, such that for every $1\leq i\leq k$ we have$$Y_i|_V=X_i|_V.$$
The proof of this lemma is left for you.

Since the $Y_i$'s agree with the $X_i$'s on an open neighborhood of $q$, the global function $p\mapsto A(Y_1(p),\ldots,Y_k(p))$ is not smooth at $q$, and (a) does not hold.